# Get notified when saved Wi-Fi network configuration is removed

Tags: android, configuration, android-wifi

The scenario is the following:

User has connected to a several Wifi profiles, so one can go to Wifi Settings, Saved Networks and see the list of previously connected and saved network configurations.

User has ability to remove a network from the list.

I need to perform some action upon removal of the network from the list. Ho do I intercept the removal action?

Thanks!

Comment: By remove you mean forget ??

Comment: @SahilBahl, yes, I meant exactly that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any information on profile management, the only piece of info is that when profile is changed (added/modified/removed) connection state change event occurs. Based on that info I got it working by doing the following:

```
if (action.equals(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)) {
            SupplicantState ss = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NEW_STATE);
            if (ss == SupplicantState.DISCONNECTED || ss == SupplicantState.COMPLETED) {
                // wifi profile got removed
            }                
        } else if (action.equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED)
                || action.equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED)) {
            // bluetooth profile got removed                
        }
```

Note, no intent is issued when inactive profile got removed.